# Best practice to return table entity by searching on view entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I currently have a database that uses views to flatten data from multiple joins and present as a read only interface to the web page. These views are essentially based on a single entity table.

For example I have a table `tblUser` and I have a view `viewUser`. The view is obviously of the data from the table along with some other lookup tables. Now I have situations where I want to update/retrieve a `tblUser` entity but based on some of the extended fields from the view, such as a domain, the user status and type.

So my question would be, what is the best way to check for and retrieve a table entity based on search criteria that is only available in the view? Currently I do something like this:

```
    viewUser view = context.viewUsers.SingleOrDefault(a => a.Logon == 'test' && a.Domain == 'test' && !a.Deleted);
    tblUser user = (view != null) ? context.tblUsers.Single(a => a.ID == view.ID) : new tblUser();
```

This just seems somewhat inefficient so I was wondering if there was a better approach to this as my searching did not really reveal anything similar to my exact question.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems about right. I would change the `.SingleOrDefault()` and `.Single()` to `.FirstOrDefault()` and `.First()` for performance.

But another question remains. Is your `viewUser` and `tblUser` exactly the same?
Just a hind also, naming classes like `viewUser` should be `ViewUser` and `TblUser`

Comment: The table and view are different, the view contains (and is based on) the table data but also has joins with other tables.

I also used the Single methods as I want to make sure I am getting a single/unique record.

Comment: `First` will return the first item to match your query and as soon as the match is done, it returns a singel item only. `Singel` will on the other hand go through a whole list, even if match was done. But your query is not off. My question about the views was just out of curiosity. Hope it helped?